# OCaml iterate through 2-dimensional list

Tags: ocaml

For example if there is a two-dimensional list :

```
let two_list = [[1;2;3];
                [4;5;6];
                [7;8;9]];;
```

how can I iterate through this list without using List modules.

Comment: This seems like a transcribed  homework question, so it wouldn't be productive just to write code for you. If you show some code that you've written and ask a specific question you'll get better help here on StackOverflow. There are a few good ways to write iterative code in OCaml. You can write a recursive function (or two recursive functions, one for each type of list) or you can just write full-on imperative code using rerences to traverse the lists and while loops to control the iteration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the `List` module you would write:

```ml
let two_list = [
  [1;2;3];
  [4;5;6];
  [7;8;9]
]

let () =
  List.iter (fun l -> List.iter print_int l) two_list
```

So, if you want to do the same without using the `List` module, all you have to do is to write your own `list_iter` function and use it instead of `List.iter`:

```ml
let two_list = [
  [1;2;3];
  [4;5;6];
  [7;8;9]
]

let rec list_iter f = function
  | [] -> ()
  | hd::tail -> begin
    f hd;
    list_iter f tail
  end

let () =
  list_iter (fun l -> list_iter print_int l) two_list
```

Comment: Note: the `begin` and `end` here are unnecessary.